What is a good framework for breakup conversation with my girlfriend after a life changing injury?
This question is a follow up to my other question here
My girlfriend whom I have been dating for 8 months is quadriplegic due to a complete SCI due to sporting accident. She needs near constant, daily care with activities of daily living such as:

Dressing
Washing and personal hygiene
Feeding
Continence care

I plan on talking to her about how her injury will impact the viability of our young relationship (less than 1 year dating), following the advice in the only answer I got. After doing some research, I have a better understanding of what her care needs are. Financial costs can easily surpass 200k just for first year, to include expenses such as the below. After reading more, the costs cited from above source are average costs, hence  costs could be underestimated in my case. Furthermore, these estimates do not take into consideration sudden and unexpected medical costs. She can no longer work in her old field or role due to disability. The government where I live does not allow family to serve as paid caregivers and private insurance won't cover cost of direct support assistants / long term caregivers.

Rehabilitation care
Physical and occupational therapy
Medications and medical supplies (e.g: pain medicine, continence care supplies, wheelchair etc.)
Home remodeling for accessibility
Subsequent medical care (surgery , follow up care for complications etc.)

After thinking of my lifestyle (e.g: full time work , outdoor activities, sports) and my needs, I am doubtful that I will be able to care for her adequately. Before her accident, we both had dreams and ambitions in what we wanted to do in our relationship but now, much has changed for us both for the worse. The caretaking is already starting to burn me out. As far as I understand, respite care is not meant for long term care, but only short term gaps. The strain of being her primary caregiver is already negatively affecting my full time work per examples below. On some days, personal time was challenging to come by between full time work, caretaking, transportation to medical appointments (OT / PT et.)

Feedback at work that I seemed distracted (admittedly true), and not as timely with tasks (again, true)

Had to decline morning meetings and ask colleagues to cover certain amount of overtime to allow for caretaking time. I am sensing growing resentment from them.

Had to have both internal and client facing meetings rescheduled and colleagues have started to notice and speak to me and complain to my manager.

Uncertainty of me being able to accept promotion or more responsibilities at work due to competing health needs of my girlfriend.

Suggestion from manager that I step back from some duties of my current job role or apply for less demanding role due to nature of what I do. (client facing resulting in much less flexibility in how I can work)

Inability to travel to client sites and company headquarters.


I feel bad about extra burden on colleagues. However, someone I love is no longer able to care for herself which is not something I can easily put aside due to injury possibility and SCI complications such as caused by inability / reduced ability to move. If certain medical interventions are not done timely (e.g: positioning or continence care), consequences can be deadly. Recently she had a close call that could have been much worse if I did not bring her to doctor.
I love my girlfriend and she is a great person (caring, funny, passionate etc.) I want what's best for her, but am no longer sure if continuing the relationship will be in either of us best interests. She is also somewhat depressed as her life has completely turned upside down and previous dreams may no longer be achievable.
She recently asked me whether if our relationship continues, I can commit to being a caregiver. We said we love each other, but privately I dont believe love alone itself is enough for our relationship to continue as is. We also discussed group care home that may be an option even though this is an institutional (vs. community) setting. It's painful that I did not have a diplomatic answer that mitigates feeling of hurt or abandonment on her part
My goals when discussing separation in this scenario:

To express that I continue to love her

To clearly state I am burned out and me being her caretaker in addition to boyfriend is not viable going forwards due to demands at work and impingement on personal time.

To preserve her dignity as a person / to not degrade her.


What's a good framework to use to discuss separation if adequate medical and social care cannot be found?
How can I have this conversation without being perceived as self centered or making my gf feel she is no longer worthy of love?
This question is different from my previous question as this question directly asks for a framework to use to raise the breakup scenario. The other question is to ask for how to discuss my concerns in general.

It looks you have been discussing with her about options of other permanent care. What did you find out? There has to be some solution since after breakup she has to be somewhere and it has to be financed. You are saying you continue to love her, do you wish to end relationship even when she is taken care of by other means?

@Piro, breakup is a contingency in case I can't care for her adequately. It hurts to see her suffer and we have discussed group care home that unfortunately is not a community (vs. institutional) setting. Right now it's the practical limits of what I can do that's hurting us both. I don't see myself being a permanent caregiver.

@Piro, also paid caregiving by family is forbidden by government. Private insurance may, but is not guaranteed to, cover 6 digit annual medical expenses. On some days, just getting alone time has been a struggle (work, caretaking, driving gf etc.)

Wow, what a tough situation. My sympathies for both of you.
First, I would suggest that you seek out a professional counselor to deal with your personal feelings of guilt while also discussing your options for explaining your feelings to your girlfriend.
Personally, I don't think you are being selfish given your relatively young relationship. Had you been dating for a few years and had discussed marriage then I may feel differently but it isn't fair of anyone to expect you to commit to a lifetime of care an financial burden after only dating for 8 months.
Ultimately, honesty will be your best ally. You cannot control how she will feel or react to you but being hurt with the truth is better than living ignorantly in a lie.

My sympathies to you both. This happened to married friends of mine about a decade ago (still married!).  He was an active athlete, and from a sudden accident, became a paraplegic paralyzed from the upper chest down.  Thus, I gained a tiny bit of insight into what's involved.
I think this situation is too serious to handle via an internet QA site.  Not that there is anything wrong with asking here.  All opinions can be helpful (as long as one remembers that, when you get down to it, this is just a place where "internet randos" voice their answers to questions, and other "internet randos" vote on those answers). I'm interested to read what my fellow "randos"  write.  But, like community member rhoona, I think seeking assistance from a professional therapist (or better yet, psychologist) is your best choice because you love your girlfriend and hopefully love yourself.
Something to discuss with a professional therapist (in a space of honesty and non-judgement, and certainly no judgement from me): Who will her caregiver be, if not you? That's not to say her caregiver can only be you. But just that she likely will need help and that you love her.  Separately, kindly note that caregiving is an art and a science, and you are understandably new to it, which explains many of your experiences.  Learning about caregiving, at any level, is always requisite to being successful at it.
Also, you seem very concerned about the financial side.  Don't be.  First, of all, trust me, money does not bring happiness.  That's one of the biggest fallacies in many places on the little planet we share.  I've been around people of all walks of life, and the only certain correlation I've witnesses between money and happiness is that most wealthy people are miserable and empty inside.  As the wise saying goes: Mo' money, mo' problems.
On the topic of money, even if the two of you eventually do get married, her injury took place before your marriage.  Thus, a qualified financial advisor will likely be able to prevent her medical expenses from impacting you much, if at all.
SCI (Spinal Cord Injury) support groups can be a great resource to learn about these topics too.
I wish you the both the best on your journey, whether as a couple, as friends, or as two separate people sharing our little planet.

Yes, financial costs are a serious concern of mine. GF can no longer work in her former field due to disability. Private insurance can be a hassle and is not guaranteed to cover expenses even though  we had no denials so far. Although my job in management pays very well, 6 digit and 5 digit medical expenses per year for life is not a small concern.

These costs likely will not be your responsibility. She will incur expenses and find a way to pay them (or have them forgiven) with or without you. With financial costs being a serious concern, my recommendation is to contact SCI support organizations. Get involved with support groups. You'll be able to learn from the success of others instead of fearing negative possibilities. You can also spend a small amount of money on a good financial advisor who is an expert on this particular topic. Hopefully these tips will lower your stress and hers, which I think may benefit you both.

With your friend, did the injury occur before or after they married , and if before, how far along in the relationship? Were they relatively young (20-30) Given caretaking is a draining full time job for activities of daily living, how did they balance between work and personal time and not blur role of lover vs. caregiver? Sometimes, I feel less like bf than caregiver. Basically, how did they avoid burnout? If you can add these details, I may accept this answer.
